# Query Dynamic Linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I need to create a dynamic query where the variable `DayOfWeek.Monday` is dynamic, how can I set?

```
DataClassesPDataContext pe = new DataClassesPDataContext();
var qry = from p in pe.R
          join q in pe.V on p.V equals q.V_
          where p.Data < data 
          where q.I == `v`
          where p.Data.DayOfWeek == `DayOfWeek.Monday`
          select(p.Q);

return qry.ToList().Average();
```

Comment: Don't do ToList() before calling Average(), as this will pull all the values into memory first. Instead, do Average() directly on the query to do all calculation in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract `DayOfWeek` into a variable

```
var day = DayOfWeek.Monday;

var qry = ...
      where p.Data.DayOfWeek = day
```

But be aware. `DayOfWeek` cannot be used if you execute the query against `Entity Framework`